# Google Charts Bar Graph

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to create a graph that has the animation but also alternating colours
I am able to make the graph show alternating colours, but the second colour doesn't animate, it just appears after everything has loaded

my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function drawChart() {
          // Create and populate the data table.
        var option = {title:"Some Graph that doesn't actually show anything",
                     width:900, height:500,
                     animation: {duration: 2000, easing: 'out',},
                     vAxis: {title: "Yearly Spending"},
                     isStacked:true,
                     hAxis: {title: "Some Amount", minValue:0, maxValue:100},
                     series: [{color: '#5B6770', visibleInLegend: true}, {color: '#CF4520', visibleInLegend: true}]     
                     };
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();    
        data.addColumn('string', 'N');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Percent');
        data.addRow(['2003', 0]);
        data.addRow(['2004', 0]);
        data.addRow(['2005', 0]);
        data.addRow(['2006', 0]);
        data.addRow(['2007', 0]);
        data.addRow(['2008', 0]);
        data.addRow(['2009', 0]);
        data.addRow(['2010', 0]);
        data.addRow(['2011', 0]);
        data.addRow(['2012', 0]);
        data.addRow(['2013', 0]);
        data.addColumn('number', 'Other');

        // Create and draw the visualization.
        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
        chart.draw(data, option);
        data.setValue(0, 1, 75);
        data.setValue(1, 2, 55);
        data.setValue(2, 1, 30);
        data.setValue(3, 2, 75);
        data.setValue(4, 1, 65);
        data.setValue(5, 2, 20);
        data.setValue(6, 1, 56);
        data.setValue(7, 2, 75);
        data.setValue(8, 1, 55);
        data.setValue(9, 2, 63);
        data.setValue(10, 1, 48);
        chart.draw(data, option);
      }

      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

how can I make it so all the bars animate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you originally initialize the graph, you have null values in column 3 (since you add the graph but no row values). As a result, I don't think the API is animating those values. If you change your code as follows, it animates all the bars for me:

```
function drawChart() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var option = {title:"Some Graph that doesn't actually show anything",
                width:900, height:500,
                animation: {duration: 2000, easing: 'out',},
                vAxis: {title: "Yearly Spending"},
                isStacked:true,
                hAxis: {title: "Some Amount", minValue:0, maxValue:100},
                series: [{color: '#5B6770', visibleInLegend: true}, {color: '#CF4520', visibleInLegend: true}]     
               };
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();    
  data.addColumn('string', 'N');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Percent');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Other');
  data.addRows([
    ['2003', 0, 0],
    ['2004', 0, 0],
    ['2005', 0, 0],
    ['2006', 0, 0],
    ['2007', 0, 0],
    ['2008', 0, 0],
    ['2009', 0, 0],
    ['2010', 0, 0],
    ['2011', 0, 0],
    ['2012', 0, 0],
    ['2013', 0, 0]
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(data, option);
  data.setValue(0, 1, 75);
  data.setValue(1, 2, 55);
  data.setValue(2, 1, 30);
  data.setValue(3, 2, 75);
  data.setValue(4, 1, 65);
  data.setValue(5, 2, 20);
  data.setValue(6, 1, 56);
  data.setValue(7, 2, 75);
  data.setValue(8, 1, 55);
  data.setValue(9, 2, 63);
  data.setValue(10, 1, 48);
  chart.draw(data, option);
}
```

I cleaned up the code a bit to make it easier to see what you are doing when defining the data, using the `addRows` method, and adding all the column assignments first. Otherwise the code is identical to yours.